Trying to use Moveit2 with Python and Gazebo but there appears to be a mismatch in the times they use, how to fix it?
[moveit_2014113509.moveit.ros.current_state_monitor]: Didn't receive robot state (joint angles) with recent timestamp within 10.000000 seconds. Requested time 1728236926.979074, but latest received state has time 34.730000.

I'm getting the above error message when trying to use Moveit2 with python for my application (based on this https://github.com/moveit/moveit2_tutorials/blob/main/doc/examples/motion_planning_python_api/scripts/motion_planning_python_api_tutorial.py). Am I correct in interpreting that gazebo is correctly using sim_time but Moveit is not? If so, how can I make MoveItPy use sim time?
